# Infuriating empty list in Spring form / controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a list of objects from form inputs.  The objects are the same but their values may differ, it's essentially a menu.

I'm still getting to grips with Spring/Thymeleaf which is adding some level of complexity to what feels like a simple task.

I've a class for the menu, a simple POJO, there is then a list of these defined as a data member in the bean itself:

```
    private ArrayList<GuestMenuOptions> guestMenus;
```

I've read many posts, tried many things and am on the verge of softly resting my head against the table.

I've had several errors, most of which either tell me that the list cannot be found or that the list is empty - it's currently in  stable condition where the list, no matter what I try, will not be populated, even when I load in default values...unfortunately my debugger has died which is not helping.

Any help is appreciated. thank you

EntryController:

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/")
public String indexPage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("childMenuOptions", generateChildMenus());

    //not sure if this is neccesary...
    ArrayList<GuestMenuOptions>guestMenus = new ArrayList<>();
    GuestMenuOptions ad1 = new GuestMenuOptions();
    GuestMenuOptions ad2 = new GuestMenuOptions();
    guestMenus.add(ad1);
    guestMenus.add(ad2);

    GuestContactBean ctb = new GuestContactBean();
    ctb.setGuestMenus(guestMenus);

    model.addAttribute("guestContactBean", ctb);
    model.addAttribute("formBackingBean", new FormBackingBean());
    return "index";
}
```

Form:

```
<form modelAttribute="guestBean" class="contact_form" name="rsvp" role="form" th:object="${formBackingBean}" th:action="@{/sendRsvp}" method="post">
                            <div class="row">

 <div class="form-group">
                                                            <select name="ad1Starter" id="starterMealAdult1">
                                                                <option value="!!!">-Starter-</option>
                                                                <option th:field="${guestContactBean.guestMenus[0].starter}" th:each="entry : ${adultMenuOptions.get('starter').entrySet()}" th:value="${entry.key}" th:text="${entry.value}">
                                                                </option>
                                                            </select>
                                                        </div>
<input type="submit"guest name="submit" class="btn default-btn btn-block" value="Send RSVP">
```

RequestController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sendRsvp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String sendRsvp(@ModelAttribute("guestContactBean") GuestContactBean guestContactBean,
                               @ModelAttribute("guestMenus") ArrayList<GuestMenuOptions>menus,
                               BindingResult result) throws MessagingException {
        smtpMailSender.send(guestContactBean);
        return "thanksMessage";
    }
```

Beans:
FormBacking is POJO with no reference to the menus at all.
GuestMenuOptions is the same with just starter, desert members
guestContactbean has not much more going on, basic fields with the addition of the list of GuestMenuOptions

```
 private String numberOfAdults;
private String eventAttending;

private ArrayList<GuestMenuOptions> guestMenus;

public ArrayList<GuestMenuOptions> getGuestMenus() {
    return guestMenus;
}
```

EDIT:
The field that populates the drop downs in working fine, it's declared as `private Map<String, Map<String, String>> adultMenuOptions;
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> childMenuOptions;`

they are then built in the controller so that each may have several options under 'starter', 'main' and desert' for example:

```
 starter.put("salmon", "Smoked Salmon");
 starter.put("pate", "Chicken Liver Pate");
```

this is then populating both the value and text of the dropdown.

If I could save the state of this Map and pass it back to the controller instead, that would also be fine but I wasn't able to why then spawned the creation of the there wrapper list.

Answer (score 1):

Please revisit http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#dropdownlist-selectors. It should be as simple as

```
class Animal {
  int id;
  String name;
}
```

then in your template:

```
<select th:field="*{animalId}">
  <option th:each="animal : ${animals}" 
          th:value="${animal.id}" 
          th:text="${animal.name}">Wireframe</option>
</select>
```

I think your code is all over the place and you're mixing up menu selection with menu item types.

Comment: I think this is a far simpler example than what I was trying to achieve.  I've edited the question to try and make it clearer.  Would you mind taking a peek please?